# Why is my login function just redirecting without doing what is written in the func

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I spent hours but I don't know where the mistake is.
I am trying flask right now and wanted to implement a login page.
But the login is not working, it is just forwarding without checking, what am I doing wrong?

This is the login function:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
name = request.form.get('name')
password = request.form.get('password')
remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

user = User.query.filter_by(name=name).first()

if user is None or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
    flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
    return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

else:
    return redirect(url_for('profile.profile'))

return render_template('login.html')
```

Whenever I try to visit "http://localhost../login" it is just redirecting to /profile where I just want to redirect when the login was successfull.
I spent almost all day to look for solutions in the internet and tried a lot of things, but it won't work.

Here is the hierarchy of my application:

```
├── app
│   ├── app.db
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── base
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── chat
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── home
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── profile
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── __pycache__
│   │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   │   └── views.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── auth.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   │   └── models.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── static
│   │   ├── base.css
│   │   ├── home.css
│   │   ├── login.css
│   │   └── main_bgr.jpg
│   └── templates
│       ├── base.html
│       ├── chat.html
│       ├── home.html
│       ├── login.html
│       ├── profile.html
│       └── signup.html
```

In the first "if"- statement I also tried:

```
if user.name == None
```

But this results in "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Comment: print `user` value after assign it

Comment: @AriaN  This was the output of print: "User None"

Comment: Try replacing `is` with `==` see if it fixed or not

Comment: @AriaN  No, still the same.

Comment: check `len(user) == 0`

Comment: @AriaN  TypeError: User has no len

Comment: I also tried if user.name == None and now there is a "Problem loading page", the page is not redirecting properly..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226208/discussion-between-arian-and-m1ghtfr3e).

Comment: "User None" is not `None`. It looks like the representation of a `User` with a username of 'None'. Does such an entry exist in your DB?

Comment: @Noah  I checked over the command line and it is the only entry, but I actually should have made entries already..

Comment: I made it work redirecting correctly, but now I see that it is actually not really getting the name, it is always None

Comment: I'm guessing the 'name' form entry is empty or non-existent by the time you're reading it here. Perhaps a similar problem elsewhere has caused a bogus user with a username of (literally) 'None' to get created.

Comment: @Noah  I guess I realized the problem. "user = User.query[...]" is executed before the lines before with "request.form.get". So this is problematic, but I don't find a way to solve this..

Comment: So I have some questions, first off, what page is it redirecting to and what page do you think it should be redirecting to?  It looks like you will never hit the login.html page (your if else will always give you a redirect before you get there).  Second, you password hash may be an issue, but we don't have that function to look at here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am entirely sure if this will work , but I noticed that there is no conditional for  if the method is POST or GET

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
   if request.method == "POST" :
       name = request.form.get('name')
       password = request.form.get('password')
       remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

       user = User.query.filter_by(name=name).first()

       if user is None or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
           flash('Please check your login details and try again.')
           return redirect(url_for('auth.login'))

       else:
           return redirect(url_for('profile.profile'))

return render_template('login.html')
```

Now again , I'm sorry if this does not solve the problem .

Comment: No, it didn't work, in fact it is just making GET requests but no POST request

Answer (score 0):

I changed it a bit to this:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    ''' Login Method '''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print('post')
        name = request.form.get('name')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        remember = True if request.form.get('remember') else False

        # = User(name=name, password=password)
        user = User.query.filter_by(name=name).first()

        if not user or not check_password_hash(user.password, password):
            return render_template('login.html')#redirect(url_for('auth.login'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html')

    return redirect(url_for('home.home'))
```

And now it is working! :) Thank you @Vishnu Joshi so much, your approach helped me fixing it!

Comment: Glad to know it helped !